# Custom SQL in Apache Superset Metrics

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I can't seem to count the number of values in a given column using the Custom SQL in Apache Superset Metrics.

I want a metric that displays the number of Win or Losses from a specified column in my virtual dataset that has "Win" and "Lose" as it's values. But when I enter what I enter below it says it's wrong.

```
COUNT(win_lose_status) WHERE win_lose_status LIKE 'Win'
```

I'm quite befuddled on how it works.

Comment: Please don't post pictures, instead post your code.

Comment: My bad, new here. I've edited the post accordingly.